# Why is my event handler null?

Tags: c#, events, delegates, inotifypropertychanged

I've got quite simple problem but gives me a headache and I'm wasting too much time. I've ran out of ideas anyway:)
For some reason I can't pass the value of my property variable to my event handler. Here is what I've got , an for me everything is fine but it won't work:(
[image]
[image]

Any idea why it's not passing the actual value of the variable? Thanks in advance:)

Comment: Have You assign handler to this event anywhere?

Comment: What do you mean "the actual value of the variable"? We can clearly see that the string "Moves" has been passed to the `onPropertyChanged` method. The title of the question indicates that you're wondering about the event being null, can you clarify what exactly the problem is here? The event handler is null because nobody has added an event handler to it.

Answer (score 0):

Just as the name suggests, `propertyName` should contain the property's name, not value. Also see [PropertyChangedEventHandler](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [PropertyChangedEventArgs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.propertychangedeventargs%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) on MSDN for more details.

As to why your event handler `null`, I suspect you haven't subscribed to it. You should have something like the following somewhere in your program:

```
obj.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(obj_PropertyChanged);

private void obj_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
  ....
}
```

then when `obj.Moves` changes `obj_PropertyChanged` will be called.

I understand your confusion, so let me give a little more explanations. Suppose you have two classes `A` and `B`, and you want `B` to be notified when a property of `A` is changed. Then you can make `A` implement INotifyPropertyChanged, and make `B` subscribe to the PropertyChanged event of `A`, like the following:

```
public class A: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
  private int moves;
  public int Moves
  {
    get { return moves; }
    set
    {
      if (value != moves) {
        moves = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("Moves");
      }
    }
  }

  public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

  private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
  {
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
      PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
  }
}

public class B
{
  private A a = new A();

  public B()
  {
    a.PropertyChanged += new PropertyChangedEventHandler(a_PropertyChanged);
  }

  private void a_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
  {
    ....
  }
}
```

With the above, `B.a_PropertyChanged` will be called whenever `A.Moves` is changed. More precisely, if `b` is an instance of `B`, then `b.a_PropertyChanged` will be called whenever `b.a.Moves` is changed. Also please note how my implementation of the setter of `Moves` differs from yours.

Comment: It's interface INotifyPropertyChanged , so You call it in the setter of the object. The class that implements it automatically subscribes to it.